# Computing $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log(x)}{\sqrt x(1+{x^2})}dx$.

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration, closed-form

I would like to compute the following integral :
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log(x)}{\sqrt x(1+{x^2})}dx$$ using Residue theorem.
I took the contour corresponding to half of the "donuts" $\{r<|z|<R\}$.
So by theorem and an classical argument we have 
$I=2i\pi Res(f,i)$. 
My problem here, is that I need ton compute the residue for the principal argument of $\log(z)$ and $\sqrt{z}$. 
How can I do that ?

Note Bene, apologies for the 'unclear' question but I am on my mobile.

Comment: Please review the edits to ensure that the integral form matches what you intend...

Comment: @abiessu Personally I would suspect that $\sqrt{x} (1 + x+ x^2)$ was meant in the denominator.

Comment: @quid: good point

Comment: Hint: $\partial_a x^a = log(x)x^a$. Now use a dogbone contour.

Comment: the result should be $-\frac{\pi^2}{3}$

Comment: @abiessu done. My problem is just to compute the residue of $f$ at $i$.

Comment: $\log(i)=i\pi/2, \sqrt{i}=e^{i \pi/4}$

Comment: @tired indeed... Thanks ^^

Comment: @ Dr. Sonnhard Graubner: Maple says $-1/4\,{\pi }^{2}\sqrt {2}. $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sub $x=y^2$ and the integral becomes

$$4 \int_0^{\infty} dy \frac{\log{y}}{1+y^4} $$

So consider

$$\oint_C dz \frac{\log^2{z}}{1+z^4} $$

where $C$ is a keyhole contour of outer radius $R$ and inner radius $\epsilon$ about the positive real axis.  In the limit as $R \to \infty$ and $\epsilon \to 0$, the contour integral is equal to

$$-i 4 \pi \int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{\log{x}}{1+x^4} + 4 \pi^2 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x^4} $$

By the residue theorem, the contour integral is equal to $i 2 \pi$ times the sum of the residues at the poles of the integrand, or

$$i 2 \pi \left[\frac{(i \pi/4)^2}{4 e^{i 3 \pi/4}} +\frac{(i 3\pi/4)^2}{4 e^{i 9 \pi/4}}+\frac{(i 5 \pi/4)^2}{4 e^{i 15 \pi/4}}+\frac{(i 7 \pi/4)^2}{4 e^{i 21 \pi/4}}\right ] = \frac{\sqrt{2} \pi^3}{4} (4+i)$$

Now, by the residue theorem again, we may find similarly that**

$$-i 2 \pi \int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x^4} = i 2 \pi \left[\frac{i \pi/4}{4 e^{i 3 \pi/4}} +\frac{i 3\pi/4}{4 e^{i 9 \pi/4}}+\frac{i 5 \pi/4}{4 e^{i 15 \pi/4}}+\frac{i 7 \pi/4}{4 e^{i 21 \pi/4}}\right ] = -i \frac{\sqrt{2} \pi^2}{2}$$

$$\implies \int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x^4} = \frac{\sqrt{2} \pi}{4} $$

Putting all of the above results together, we find that

$$ \int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{\log{x}}{1+x^4} = -\frac{\sqrt{2} \pi^2}{16} $$

so that the original integral is

> $$\int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{\log{x}}{\sqrt{x}(1+x^2)} = -\frac{\sqrt{2} \pi^2}{4} $$

** I know there are easier ways to get the value of that integral, but I prefer to be consistent with the method I use.

Comment: In fact, I just start residue theorem, so I am not looking for the easier way but an instructive one, as yours, well explained. Thanks.

Comment: How/Why did you decide $\log^2z$ should be considered?

Comment: @grdgfgr: generally, to evaluate an integral over $\log^n{x}$ using the residue theorem, one considers a contour integral over $\log^{n+1}{z}$ using a keyhole contour.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $u=\sqrt{x}$ to avoid the square root and then $x=u^2$ and the integral becomes
$$ I=4\int_0^\infty\frac{\log u}{1+u^4}du. $$
Then use the contour $\Gamma=\{z| r\le|z|\le R\}\setminus [r,R]$ to work on the function
$$ f(z)=\frac{\log^2 z}{1+z^4} $$
and you will get the anwser.